# Random forest tuning mtry - tuneRF versus caret

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, hyperparameter

Multiple posts (below) show that tuneRF and caret (or manually tuning) produce quite different recommendations for mtry. Why are these different? Which approach is more reliable for controlling overfitting?

https://github.com/rjonczy/r-blogs-examples/blob/master/random-forest-tuning.R
https://machinelearningmastery.com/tune-machine-learning-algorithms-in-r/

Comment: You can look at the OOBCurvePars function of the OOBCurve R package. With this function you can visualize your performance dependent on your mtry values. Looking at the shape of the curve will help you a lot.